# How avoid docker-compose up ignoring a dockerfile?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, airflow, dbt

I'm trying to modify an Airflow docker-compose set-up with an extended image from a Dockerfile to have dbt installed on the container but the docker-compose file seems to be ignoring the Dockerfile: the different airflow containers are launched and run correctly but not a single one has dbt (fully) installed. I get the following error :

```
root@42b2358a7792:/opt/airflow# dbt --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/bin/dbt", line 5, in <module>
    from dbt.main import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dbt'
```

The docker-compose.yml file:

```
version:                                        "3.7"
#https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#using-extensions-as-fragments

# Airflow extensions
x-airflow-common:                               &airflow-common
  build:                                        .
  environment:                                  &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR:                    CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN:            postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND:            db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL:                redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY:                  ''
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES:               'true'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKEND:                 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'
  volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins

  user:                                         "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:${AIRFLOW_GID:-50000}"
  depends_on:
    redis:
      condition:                                service_healthy
    postgres:
      condition:                                service_healthy


services:
 
  # Database
  postgres:
      image:                                    postgres:13
      environment:
        POSTGRES_USER:                          airflow
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD:                      airflow
        POSTGRES_DB:                            airflow
      volumes:
        - postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      healthcheck:
        test:                                   ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
        interval:                               5s
        retries:                                5
      restart:                                  always
      ports:
              - 5432:5432

  # Airflow services
  redis:
      image:                                    redis:latest
      container_name:                           airflow-redis
      ports:
        - 6379:6379
      healthcheck:
        test:                                   ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
        interval:                               5s
        timeout:                                30s
        retries:                                50
      restart:                                  always
  airflow-webserver:
      <<:                                       *airflow-common
      container_name:                           airflow-webserver
      command:                                  webserver
      ports:
        - 8080:8080
      healthcheck:
        test:                                   ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
        interval:                               10s
        timeout:                                10s
        retries:                                5
      restart:                                  always
  airflow-scheduler:
      <<:                                       *airflow-common
      container_name:                           airflow-scheduler
      command:                                  scheduler
      healthcheck:
        test:                                   ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type SchedulerJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
        interval:                               10s
        timeout:                                10s
        retries:                                5
      restart:                                  always
  airflow-worker:
      <<:                                       *airflow-common
      container_name:                           airflow-worker
      command:                                  celery worker
      healthcheck:
        test:
          - "CMD-SHELL"
          - 'celery --app airflow.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}"'
        interval:                               10s
        timeout:                                10s
        retries:                                5
      restart:                                  always

  airflow-init:
      <<:                                       *airflow-common
      container_name:                           airflow-init
      command:                                  version
      environment:
        <<:                                     *airflow-common-env
        _AIRFLOW_DB_UPGRADE:                    'true'
        _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE:               'true'
        _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME:             ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME:-airflow}
        _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD:             ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD:-airflow}



volumes:
  workspace:
     name:                                      ${WORKSPACE_DOCKER_MOUNT}
  data:
     name:                                      ${DATA_DOCKER_MOUNT}
  db:
     name:                                      ${DB_DOCKER_MOUNT}
  postgres-db-volume:
```

The dockerfile:

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.1.0
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
         vim \
  && apt-get autoremove -yqq --purge \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN apt-get install -y git libpq-dev python-dev python3-pip
RUN apt-get remove python-cffi
RUN pip install --upgrade cffi
RUN pip install cryptography~=3.4
RUN pip install dbt==0.19.0
```

I have tried directly building the image are the service level and changing the Dockerfile with only RUN pip install dbt==0.19.0 but it won't work.
The only alternative, which I would like to avoid is manual installation.

Any ideas why docker-compose is ignoring the Dockerfile ?

Comment: My guess from your very partial information is that you are launching a bare `docker-compose up` which finds an existing image that it launches. If you want to refresh your extended image, you need to either `docker-compose build [--pull]` prior to launching your project or force build on start with `docker-compose up --build`. For more quick info => `docker-compose build --help` and `docker-compose up --help`

Comment: Tried, it gives more details but the error isn't solved..

Answer (score 3):

There are several problems with your Dockerfile.

I recommend running `docker build .` once once you prepare your Dockerfile to check if it is correct.

It will fail because you have not changed the user to root temporarily when running apt-get as described: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/build.html#adding-new-apt-package

Also even if you fix it, your Dockerfile will fail because your `apt-get install` command is split into two. First one removes all the cache (the one installing vim which is most likely not what you want to do). The second `apt-get install` will fail because it will not have a cache of apt and will not find your pacakges. So seems you've never actually built your docker image.

Also it will fail because `python-cffi` is not installed by default in Airflow image and trying to remove it will fail.

I made a few small modifications in your file to make it builds (but I am not sure if the image is what you want):

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.1.0
USER root
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y git libpq-dev python-dev python3-pip \
  && apt-get autoremove -yqq --purge \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
USER airflow
RUN pip install --upgrade cffi
RUN pip install cryptography~=3.4 dbt==0.19.0
```

Another problem with your Dockerfile is that it is not optimized for size (as all production images should be). By addding python-dev you are adding a lot of packages (compilers and such ~ which will make your image far bigger than it should be. If you make it works I recommend you to go "customization" route (https://airflow.apache.org/docs/docker-stack/build.html#customizing-the-image) which should make your image much smaller.

The image built as above is 1.5GB. The original airflow image (Heavily optimized for size) is 882MB. So by adding python-dev and installing dbt the size of it is increased by whopping 70% (!). It should be less than 1GB if you use "customization" route.

You can read more about why docker size matters for example here
https://semaphoreci.com/blog/2018/03/14/docker-image-size.html

Comment: Thanks for the information and new Dockerfile. Once launch docker-compose up -d --build, I see each container going through the Dockerfile installation process but when I access any of the containers, I still get the same error. It can't seem to find the dbt package. Could it be linked to python versions or installation pathway ?

Comment: How do you access the containers? For me import dbt work when I run the image:

Comment: ...
Successfully built 4959c55395ef

docker run -it 4959c55395ef bash


airflow@728245bd4814:/opt/airflow$ python
Python 3.6.13 (default, May 12 2021, 16:48:24) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dbt
>>> quit

Comment: Did you try to build and run the image yourself? Did you check if import works for you? Are you sure the images that are built are use by docker-compose ?

I think it would be great if you provide some steps you tried to analyse the problem before posting "it does not work" , otherwise it looks like you are not even trying...

Comment: Right, sorry for the lack of details. 
Running docker build . :
Successfully built c9d6c2d00a4c
Accessing docker container:
sudo docker run -it c9d6c2d00a4c bash
Testing dbt version:
installed version: 0.19.0
   latest version: 0.20.0

Running docker-compose up -d --build:
...
---> Using cache
 ---> c9d6c2d00a4c
Successfully built c9d6c2d00a4c

Accessing the relevant docker container with:
 sudo docker exec -it 22852faced2d /bin/bash

Testing dbt version:
dbt --version

Result:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dbt'

Comment: `sudo docker exec -it 22852faced2d /bin/bash`  will not work. You need to use /entrypoint which is the entrypoint of the image - it sets all the variables that are needed by Airlfow to run (likely you have no HOME directory set properly).

Comment: docker exec -it elegant_zhukovsky /entrypoint bash
airflow@0666f1b6ad88:/opt/airflow$ python 
Python 3.6.13 (default, May 12 2021, 16:48:24) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dbt
>>>